# Installing SSRS 2019 standalone

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2019

Our databases are on SQL Server 2012 SP4 and we have been using SSRS 2012 for reporting.

With Microsoft making SSRS 2019 available now, I am wondering if we can install SSRS 2019 as a standalone product and using it for reporting (Without impacting the databases we already have on SQL Server 2012.

In this case, how much will we be charged for SQL Server Reporting Services 2019?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Under the Per Core licensing model, each server running SQL Server
>   2019 software or any of its components (such as **Reporting Services** or
>   Integration Services) must be assigned an appropriate number of SQL
>   Server 2019 core licenses. The number of core licenses needed, depends
>   on whether customers are licensing the physical server or individual
>   virtual operating system environments (OSEs).

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2019-pricing

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. The business doesn't want to take databases that are currently on SQL 2012 to 2019 yet. the Is it possible to install SQL 2019, but only use SSRS 2019 on the databases which are on SQL 2012?

Comment: It is no problem. If it is the answer,you can accept it.